# Parse an HTML string without invoking network operations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension that scrapes the results from a remote site. I use `fetch` to successfully get the HTML string of the page, and now I need to query for a single node.

I've tried the following 2 approaches (given `html` string, and `query` string):

1. `let node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(html).querySelector(query);`
2. `let mock = document.createElement('div');
   mock.innerHTML = html;
   let node = mock.querySelector(query);`

In both cases, I get the text I need, and can parse it properly.
But I get tons of network errors in the console, where the page's assets (scripts, images, svg etc.) try to load, and are blocked by the extension's policy (as well they should - not complaining about that).

My question is: how do I parse an HTML string, or get the element you need, without triggering the network operations? And if possible, without involving jQuery - I'd like to keep this vanilla.

Comment: Yes! That works! Thanks @wOxxOm! Add it as an answer, so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safe [DOMParser API](http://devdocs.io/dom/domparser) can parse HTML since Chrome 30, FF 12, IE 10 and in other modern browsers:

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
var element = doc.querySelector('a.foo-bar');
```

It can also parse SVG, XML if you specify the corresponding [MIME type parameter](http://devdocs.io/dom/domparser#Parsing_an_SVG_or_HTML_document).